# Jquery dropdown selection boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a pretty easy question, how can i select a value individual values with Jquery if I have sets(rows) of the same drop-down boxes?

http://jsfiddle.net/Bw4cr/2/

As in I want to return(kite) or (22) depending on which dropdown I clicked on.

**> Jquery**

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
   var selectVal= $(this).siblings('select').val();
    alert(selectVal);
});
```

> **HTML**

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Tie</th> <th>Pie</th><th>Lie</th>
</thead>

<tr>
<td><select class="Member" name="options">
    <option value="1">kite</option>
    <option value="2">flag</option>
    <option value="3">ball</option>
    <option value="4">road</option></td>
    <td>
    <select class="Member" name="options" price="200">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option></td>

    <td>
    <select class="Member" name="options" price="200">
    <option value="1">11</option>
    <option value="2">22</option>
    <option value="3">33</option>
    <option value="4">44</option></td>

    </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the **Text content** , then use

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

If you want to get the **Current value**

```
$(this).val();
```

**Code**

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
    var selectVal= $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    alert(selectVal);
});​
```

**[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Bw4cr/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

just change :

```
var selectVal= $(this).siblings('select').val();
```

to

```
var selectVal= $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `value` property then

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
   var selectVal = $(this).val();
    alert(selectVal);
});​
```

If you want to show the text in the dropdown then Sushants answer is appropriate

Fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/Bw4cr/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map() method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get a series of values from all the `<select>` tags, like so:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
    var selectVal= $(this).parent().siblings().andSelf().find('select').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    alert(selectVal);
    // alerts something like "2,1,1"
});​
```

Updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EW3pT/).

Answer (score 0):

The other selects are not `siblings` of the changed select as they all inside `td` tag,
so use:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
    var selectVal=$(this).parent().siblings('td').find('select').map(function() {
       return $(this).val();
    });
 //delete junk
    delete(selectVal.context);
    delete(selectVal.prevObject);
    console.log(selectVal);
});​
```

but this will return only other two (not just changed values) which is probably not you want, so next code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=options]', function() {
//this will return array
    var selectVal=$(this).parents('tr').find('td > select').map(function() {
       //use here alert or whatever you want
       return $(this).val();
    });
    //delete junk
    delete(selectVal.context);
    delete(selectVal.prevObject);
    console.log(selectVal);
});​
```

I not used `andSelf()` because it will change the order of the values in array.